# Why I can't able to get the User Input for The List Items through the Console Window?

Tags: c#, arraylist, console-application

I'm new to Programming. Now I have to learn C# List Items.

**My Expectation:**

1. Create an Empty List
2. Get the Input value for this list from the user through the console
   Window.

**My Program:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


 namespace Indexof_in_List
 {
    class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation of IndexOf Method with List");
        Console.WriteLine();
    //If the user entered empty value or nothing in the console window, the window will exit automatically

        //Create an Empty List
        List<int> name = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Input values for the List");

        //Get the Inputs for the List from the Console Window
        for (int n = 0; n < name.Count; n++)
        {
            bool check;
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            check = int.TryParse(input, out int val);
            if (check)
            {
                name[n] = val;
            }
            else
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        //Implement Index of any number in the list items which you have entered to the console
        Console.WriteLine("The Index of value 10 is = {0}",name.IndexOf(10));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("The Index of value 1000 is ={0}", name.IndexOf(1000));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Console Output]

Could Anyone Tell me the solution for this C# Logic? And also tell me the reason for this failure?

And Tell me, whether my Logic is correct or not?

Comment: What is `name`? `.Count` indicates the number of items it currently contains. Did you mean `.Capacity` (if you set a collection size when you created it)?

Comment: Actually, List name should be "numbers". Unfortunately, I have mentioned it as "name"

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the definition.

Comment: Yup @John. I have included

Comment: I´d suggest that in case user did not enter 10 or 1000, `IndexOf` will return `-1`, which I´m not sure you want to see in your message `"The Index of value 1000 is =-1"`. You should probably handle that case with a different message, something like `"Value 1000 not contained in list"`.

Comment: I think you have to add to list not to assign the value `name.Add(val)`.

Comment: You would have more success with name.Add as while you declared it can hold so many, the dont exist until you add them

Comment: name.Count() return 0, because you just initialized the list. Change it to a static number instead, or get the amount of the numbers from the user before the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues:

1. `Count` retrieves the *current number of items* in your list.
2. You have created your list using the default constructor, so the `Capacity` is also 0. Because of this you *can't* loop from 0 to `name.Capacity`.
3. You are trying to add items using an index. You can only access *existing items* using  the `name[index]` syntax.

The simplest solution is to initialize the list as you are, and simply add items:

```
List<int> name = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    bool check;
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    check = int.TryParse(input, out int val);
    if (check)
    {
        name.Add(val);
    }
    else
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

This will read 10 numbers one after the other and add them to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your valuable Comments. Finally, I have done the final changes based on your feedback.

**My Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


 namespace Indexof_in_List
 {
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation of IndexOf Method with List");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //Create an Empty List
        List<int> name = new List<int>();


        //If the user entered empty value or nothing in the console window, the window will exit automatically
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Input values for the List");

        //Get the Inputs for the List from the Console Window
        for (int n=0;n<5;n++)
        {
            bool check=false;
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            check = int.TryParse(input, out int val);
            if (check)
            {
                name.Add(val) ;
            }
            else
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        if (name.Count != 0)
        {
            //Implement Index of any number in the list items which you have entered to the console
            int index1 = name.IndexOf(10);
            Console.WriteLine("The Index of value 10 is = {0}", name.IndexOf(10));
            if (index1!=-1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number 10 found in the List");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Number 10 found in the List");
            }

            int index2 = name.IndexOf(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("The Index of value 1000 is ={0}", name.IndexOf(1000));
            if (index2 != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number 1000  found in the List");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The  Number 1000 not found in the List");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
  }
```